# How to modify Makefile parameters with mkmf

Tags: ruby, mkmf

I am trying to compile c code using rake compiler in a windows 10 environment. I am having a problem with the paths that the Makefile is generating because they have "/C/ instead of "C:". Mingw that was installed as part of the dev-kit, cannot handle this format of abs paths, I have to change it to a windows format.

Please note topdir and prefix.

Makefile:

```
srcdir = ../../../../ext/hello_world
topdir = /C/Ruby/include/ruby-2.6.0
hdrdir = $(topdir)
arch_hdrdir = C:/Ruby/include/ruby-2.6.0/x64-mingw32
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
VPATH = $(srcdir):$(arch_hdrdir)/ruby:$(hdrdir)/ruby
prefix = $(DESTDIR)/C/Ruby
```

I am able to modify the value for 'prefix' doing this in the extconf.rb file:

```
CONFIG['prefix'] = '$(DESTDIR)C:/Ruby'
```

But for any reason if I try to change the value for 'topdir', the value doesn't get overridden. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Assuming C is your operating disk have your tried just leaving it off? Generally just the leading forward slash indicates an absolute path from the disk root and will work perfectly fine e.g.  `/Ruby/include/ruby-2.6.0`

Comment: The problem is that my system can't handle paths that begin with /C/ or no C disk at all. I have to force the topdir and prefix paths to have C:/ instead of /C/.